# how to change the driver of a ole_dbconnection from oracle_32bit to oracle_64bit

Tags: installation, connections, oledb

i have the connection string of:

```
connection= new OleDbConnection("Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;UserId=userid;Password=password;
Data Source=database;OLEDB.NET=true");
```

However after Oracle_64bit driver was installed on my computer in another process this doesn't work anymore. I read something about making a connection string like:

```
Driver={Oracle in OraClient12Home1_32bit};Dbq=database;Uid=userid;Pwd=password;"
```

I can't make that work however, and would like to hear if there's some simple fix for 32-bit to 64-bit of oledbconnection?

Answer (score 0):

Even in this day and age, Windows is *still* reliant on the good, old-fashioned DOS PATH environment variable for finding dynamically linked libraries (DLLs).

It is possible that the 64-bit installation has altered the PATH variable (usually to insert its own location at the start of the "list").  This means that the 32-bit application, while searching through the DOS PATH, will find *correctly-named* 64-bit libraries before the 32-bit ones that it requires.

Comment: So you're saying i could possibly look through the DOS PATH environment , and swap spots between 32-bit and 64-bit, so that my system will continue to use the 32-bit version? If yes, how do i then change this DOS PATH?

Comment: @Levicia: Exactly right.  You can see the PATH variable in a Command Prompt ("echo %PATH%"); it's fiddly to read, using semi-colon delimiters.  To change it (assuming you're on Windows 10) search for "Edit the System Environment Variables").
Bear in mind, though, that the /real/ trouble starts when some of your applications need to use the 64-bit drivers bit some others still need the 32-bit ones!

Comment: Thanks, i feared that's what u meant. I already tried to change the path order, however it didn't yield a different result. I'll continue to see if i can find a way to use 64-bit driver instead :)